# Keycloak terms.ftl file Url

Tags: java, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-gatekeeper

I am working on Keycloak theme. Where we define urls like href="${url.loginUrl}". i want to define terms.ftl file url variable to send in href.

I try to run href="${url.termsUrl}". but it is is not working

Answer (score -1):

I used `${url.resourcesPath}` as a base URL and I complete the URL as I want. For example, if you have your terms and conditions as a `.html` page and you want to display it in a specific `href`. You can copy (put) your page as a resource in the `resources` folder found here : `/opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/your_theme/login`
and then in your `terms.ftl` you put :

```
<a href="${url.resourcesPath}/terms-conditions.html">msg</a>
```

This will make a call to your file without defining a specific url in keycloak service.